To describe the inappropriate behavior of insulting and personal attacking, is there a phrase containing "low"?
To describe the inappropriate behavior of insulting and personal attacking, is there a phrase containing "low"? "lowball" doesn't fit, I guess. How about "playing low"?

We could consider low blow which Collins Dictionary describes in its sense 2:

a criticism or attack deemed to be unwarranted and unprincipled
It was a low blow, and possibly a political misjudgment to quash a rebellion that could humiliate the prime minister.


Perhaps worth noting that when used this way, it is a metaphor. It comes from the sport of boxing, where there are rules about what parts of the body you can strike. A low blow is a punch below the waist, and is illegal.

@PeterKirkpatrick - in the UK, I don't know about elsewhere, such a blow is very often said to be 'below the belt'. I distinctly remember my mother's awkwardness, when, aged seven, I asked her for the origin of the metaphor. She eventually said 'Boxers aren't allowed to hit each other on the legs'.

Hi, @Peter Kirkpatrick and Michael, Some memorable low blows are seen in Bowe v Golota. The last hit caused the great Bowe to retire.  He would otherwise have gone far in his career.  Subsequently when the great Lewis took on Golota, he finished him quickly to prevent such from being used.

@MichaelHarvey, great story. "Below the belt" is part of NZ English too. Personally I think boxers should get bonus points for being able to reach as low as the legs...

@PeterKirkpatrick - where I am, 'great story' is often a pass-agg way of saying 'you made it up'. I promise I didn't! Another time I heard on the BBC radio news that Sophia Loren had been charged with 'adultery'. Again Mother struggled to explain, and in the end said  'it's when two grownups marry each other when they are already married'. I didn't tell her I knew that was bigamy. I suppose it was the age at which I learned to appreciate dictionaries.

So that's a language difference between us. For me, story is entirely neutral, covering both fictional and factual narratives. I took it as a given that your story was both true and great.

@PeterKirkpatrick - I think it's a fairly modern social media thing - 'nice story, bro'... I didn't really think you were accusing me of inventing my little anecdote.

The expression "to take the low road" (the opposite of taking the high road) is often used of personal attacks and reputational smears in politics.

You could just describe the behavior as "low".
American Heritage Dictionary, sense 5:

a. Violating standards of morality or decency; base: a low stunt to pull.
b. Unrefined; coarse: low humor.

